# Why aren't more people coming to settle in Sanctuary Hills?

Tags: fallout-4

Its my personal experience that Sanctuary Hills may have a settlement problem. I made a second game after my first finished, with only the original 5 NPC's. A notion which baffled me when other, under-furnished comparatively settlements ended with settler numbers in the low twenties.

After Putting Food, Water, and Power all above 75 with a whopping 300 in defense *Using God Mode of course for the sake of testing* and a full play-through later, No one ever came to settle in my Sanctuary Hills. In fact, NPC's like the recovering Alcoholic, now  Cola-fiend from Diamond City, that I directly sent there, would disappear after the first in game week of being an established shop runner or farmer. *This particular problem happened in the original play-through as well.*

Keep in mind, the original play-through began and ended in the first week (Beginning, at Hour one of game release) of the games release, and the Test play-through within the next 2-3 weeks after. So patches may or may not have occurred within that time frame that could of affected the test, but in my case, did not.

Additional Unnecessary to ask questions are answered with, Yes, I kept my Defense score 3x's higher than my resources combined.

Yes, I put a Satellite beacon in EVERY settlement I controlled, Including Sanctuary Hills. (Though not immediately on the original Play-through.)

Yes, the first play-through was almost entirely unmodded. (Save for texture replacers.) The following were not.

Yes, I updated whenever possible. GEForce Drivers included.

Comment: I wouldn't even know this was a question if it weren't for the title.

Comment: Did you powered up your Recruitment Radio Beacon?

Comment: Did you build more beds?

Comment: By "satellite beacon", do you mean a recruitment radio beacon?

Comment: Anecdotally, I've also noticed that it seems to take much longer for Sanctuary Hills to attract a new settler via the recruitment beacon than, say, The Castle. The Castle attracted 3 settlers in what was 20 minutes of real-time play. I've gone several play sessions now with Sanctuary Hills hovering at 9 settlers, even though I have 17 beds, 18+ food and water, double defense, a recruitment beacon, and a charisma of 7.

Comment: You could try to send settlers over to Sanctuary Hills if you have the right perks leveled up.

Answer (score 1):

**Because there is noone.**

First: It doesn't matter how high your food, water and power is, for settlers to come to your settlement. It impacts only the happiness of your settlement.

I think the problem with Sanctuary is, that there really just aren't any humans around. The recruiting beacon has a limited range. Very limited. Test it out by going away from one in a straight line. you will quite soon recognise the "Recruiting signal lost" notice on the top-left of your screen. Especially if you set up a beacon in red rocket, the settlers will propably dragged there first. So, unless a patch will add some wandering wastelanders in the north-east corner of the map, Sanctuary will propably stay quite a silent little settlement (Except you send settlers from satelite settlements of course).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all the needs are met inside the settlement (you have enough water, food etc) and you have a powered recruitment beacon, then the maximum settlement size is 10 + Charisma (this number *includes* any charisma boosting wearables).

Comment: Given that this limit applies to all your settlements, and given that the asker has stated that their other settlements have quite a few more people in them, this can't be the reason.